# How do I extend a support vector machine algorithm to a high dimensional data set?

Tags: algorithm, svm

I'm trying to implement an SVM algorithm, but I'm having a hard time understanding how d-dimensional data sets are actually handled. In my particular case, each 'point' has nearly 400  identifying features.

In the two dimensional space, it basically tries to find a line between the two groups that maximizes the margin from any point on either side. I can sort of imagine what such a 'line' would look like in a d-dimensional space, but I'm completely lost on how the classification would actually work.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160495/support-vector-machines-a-simple-explanation), but I'm not getting it. I sort of get how the separation would occur after you have the classifier, but I'm lost on how to actually get the classifier.

Comment: Is your question about how the algorithm works or about visualizing it in higher dimensions?

Comment: How it works. I'm struggling to figure out how you get the hyperplane classifier

Answer (score 0):

If you can imagine how the line of the 2D case would become a d-dimensional hyperplane for higher dimensions, then you are pretty much done. The actual classification occurs when you test a point over the hyperplane, which will give you a positive number if the point belongs to class 1 or negative if it belongs to class 2.

Notice that in the formula there is no restriction for the dimension of each point:

[image]

[Image courtesy of wikipedia]

And in case you are curious about what happens with the non-linear case when you use the kernel trick, I would like to share with you a video that illustrates very well the idea.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3liCbRZPrZA